# Is it possible to create partition table SQL Server hosted on google cloud?

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform

I want to know if it is possible to create partition table with SQL Server database hosted on google cloud.
Following steps we to create partition table in SQL server:

1. Create a File Group
2. Add Files to File Group
3. Create a Partition Function with Ranges
4. Create a Partition Schema with File Groups

**But what if the SQL Server is hosted on cloud? even though the steps are same?**

Comment: Have you consulted the Documentation on Google hosted SQL Servers, to see if not being able to partition is listed in the limitations? If not, I would start there.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [article](https://www.sqlshack.com/database-table-partitioning-sql-server/):

> "Partitioning is the database process where very large tables are divided into multiple smaller parts".

As long as your schema is relational, you can create your tables as you want in CloudSQL SQLServer. There are no limitations on how you create your schema in CloudSQL. Something that you might take care is, in a long term, that your schema would be optimal for the queries you would perform. If your schema is not set right from the very beggining, you could face issues with the performance in your CloudSQL Instances.

In the [SQL Server features unavailable for Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/features#sqlserver-unavailable)  features described in the documentation, is not the partitioned tables.

Additionally, you can always check the [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/release-notes) in which you can find the releases and the features that each one includes, sometimes are patches, fixes, deprecations or new features.

On the other hand, if you have a [VM in Compute Engine with SQLServer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows#sql_server), the management is totally up to you, and has no limited features as in CloudSQL SQL Server.